# Не работают браузеры на vps ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, браузер, vps, chromium

Не работает ни одни браузер на vps ubuntu. Все(chrome, chromium, firefox) выводят:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом пинг к гуглу проходит успешно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вывод htop:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Параметры сервера: 2 ядра процессора, 2 Гб оперативной памяти, 60 Гб диска, 1 IP-адрес

Comment: Это не выглядит как проблема с интернетом. На VPS точно хватает ресурсов для нормальной работы браузера? Покажите вывод htop или другого монитора ресурсов в системе.

Comment: Что бы исключить проблемы с сетью, можно сделать, например, ```wget google.com```. Если страница скачается нормально, проблема точно не с сетью

Comment: вывод htop показал характеристики тоже написал

Comment: learn more нажмите)

Comment: не могу найти где? в htope?

Comment: @EvgeneyLebedev попробуйте `dig google.com`, возможно проблема с DNS

Comment: @Gedweb, нет оно как бы прогружает сайт а потом сразу выдает ошибку

Comment: запустите из консоли `firefox --safe-mode`, и наличие библиотек
`ldd $(which firefox)` (файл полученый which может оказаться shell-скриптом, нужно заглянуть в него)